# CGAL installation on macOS Homebrew

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew, cgal

I'm trying to install CGAL using Homebrew on macOS Mojave.
As I read on Cgal manual they recommend using these commands:

```
brew install cgal
brew install cgal-qt5
```

First command run and install cgal properly, but with the second one I get this error:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "cgal-qt5" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I have updated Homebrew but the problem is still there.

If I try to build the provided example Triangulation_2 I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/CGAL/draw_triangulation_2.h:16:10: fatal error: 
'CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h' file not found
```

I don't know if the two problems are correlated. Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need any demos, which depend on Qt5, you do not need the second option. The first one is enough. It will install CGAL in `usr/local/opt/cgal`. But since you are running the example with the `draw_` prefix that is trying to load the Qt-based basic viewer, it fails. All examples that do not depend on the Qt should run just fine. If you still need the demo, the fastest way to get it running, I would suggest, is to do

```
brew install danston/cgal/cgal-examples@5.0.1
cd /usr/local/opt/cgal-examples@5.0.1/Triangulation_2/
./draw_triangulation_2
```

This is my own brew tap, it installs the precompiled CGAL examples for macOS Mojave.

If you need later to run your own code with one of the CGAL demos, this is a bit more complicated and you should address the CGAL docs.